spring boot failed to call method from third party jar
I'm learning how to import a third party jar in springboot project and call its method, the jar is imported and project build passed, but at last it shows the class cannot be resolved. Here are the steps:

create a springboot project, create a class and maven install it in local maven repository

public class MyDemo {
    public String getStr(){
        return "this is my demo";
    }
}

2)in another project, define it in pom.xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.examples</groupId>
            <artifactId>demos</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

the package is showing in external libraries, but calling the method from the class of the jar, it shows the class cannot be resolved. Any ideas?
        com.examples.demos.MyDemo.getStr();

java: package com.examples.demos does not exist


Did you put package com.examples.demos; at the start of your MyDemo.java?
